# Page break if subreport is having odd number of page in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, subreport, page-break

I have a main report which contains a subreport only, Sub report is showing some records,

Problem is i am taking print on both side of pages. so i want a page break if subreport is having odd number of pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Reporting Services, page break can only be added between tablix, rectangles and groups within tablix. It's not support to have the page break occurs based on number of records and the current page number.